# JS/JQUERY Changing between 2 colors if previous attribute is different to next

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this possible?

Suppose I have this setup. Each div is a square representing currencies. Now, I can change every other element to whatever I want, but I have no clue how to change the color based on their value. For example, I want all iterations of GBP to be Gray - automatically next color should be Blue, then gray, then blue etc.

Its important for it to be dynamic and not be based on the div text but more on an attribute of some sort that later will be generated within php and will assign it to the currency (For example gbp has id of 1 in the datbabase, usd has an id of 2 etc. meaning that those div's will generate with the value of the id from database)

```
<div value"1"> GBP </div> < gray
<div value"1"> GBP </div> < gray
<div value"1"> GBP </div>  < gray
<div value"2"> USD</div> < blue
<div value"2"> USD</div>  < blue
<div value"2"> USD</div>  < blue
<div value"3"> CHF</div>  < gray
<div value"3"> CHF</div>  < gray
<div value"3"> CHF</div>  < gray
```

Its easty to do it statically, but im trying to make it dynamic so that every time a new record of whatever currency is added it will have the same color. Its worth to mention that the data is sorted and displayed on the website exacly as the example shown above.

Comment: `div`s don't generally have a `value` property, it might be better to use a data-attribute ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*))

Comment: get all divs with same attribute, then iterate them and change colour based if they are odd/even?

Comment: Yeah i thought of using data-attribute but i really have no clue how to wrap my head around it :(